# Checking overlap dates

Tags: vb.net

i want my code to show if the date i input is overlap or not in my database. But the problem is this code is comparing each record in my database . help me please sorry for my bad english

```
 Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    connector()
    Dim READER As MySqlDataReader

    Try
        MysqlConn.Open()
        Dim query As String
        Dim dbCheckIn, dbCheckOut As Date

        ''  query = "SELECT * FROM reservationtable WHERE CheckIn <= '" & dtpCO.Text & "' And CheckOut >= '" & dtpCI.Text & "'"
        query = "SELECT CheckIn, CheckOut FROM reservationtable"


        COMMAND = New MySqlCommand(query, MysqlConn)
        READER = COMMAND.ExecuteReader

        While READER.Read
            dbCheckIn = READER("CheckIn")
            dbCheckOut = READER("CheckOut")
            Dim a As String
            a = dbCheckIn <= dtpCO.Text And dbCheckOut >= dtpCI.Text


            If a = True Then

                MsgBox("Date Not Available!")

            ElseIf a = Not True Then

                MsgBox("Date Available!")

            End If
        End While

        updateGrid()
        MysqlConn.Close()
    Catch ex As MySqlException
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    Finally
        MysqlConn.Dispose()
    End Try

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a WHERE clause to your SQL statement to limit the results to any that would be considered an overlap, so if any records are returned it is an overlap and if none are returned it isnt. For example:

```
Dim textAsDate = New DateTime.Parse(dtpCO.Text)   

Dim query = "SELECT CheckIn FROM reservationtable
    WHERE CheckIn <= " + txtAsDate + " AND CheckOut >= " + txtAsDate

Dim command= New MySqlCommand(query, MysqlConn)

Using dr As SqlDataReader = command.ExecuteReader()

    Dim datatable= New DataTable()
    datatable.Load(dr)

    If datatable.Rows.Count > 0 Then
         ' Not available
    Else
         ' Available
    End If

End Using
```

Now you should be able to just check if there are any values returned and if so send the "Date is not available" message.

Comment: why is it sometimes didnt work? :( it always says date available

Comment: Hi there. I would try running the sql statement in SQL Server management studio with the dates you are testing and seeing what happens. The query above will only return rows where the checkin date is less than or equal to the date passed in AND the checkout date is greater than or equal to the date passed in. Change the query to also return the CheckOut field and then while debugging inspect the results and see what the checkIn and checkout values are and if the passed in date does fall within the two. If you can, post the CheckIn and CheckOut values returned as well as the date passed in.